# With Modelbuilder, how to iterate field value so final output table is empty if input is empty?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, table, excel

I have created a model which will output two Excel tables (the green circles at the end) per state. I am using "Iterate Field Values" to go through each state to create the tables. While this gives me each table I need, the problem is that when a table is empty, the model STILL outputs a table for that state - with rows for every state (all input).

Goal:

1) to have **NO** table output if there is no data in the table

*or*

2) to output a table that has empty fields

I would prefer the latter option. For **Iterate Field Values** I tried both checking 'Skip Null Values' and leaving it empty. Neither resolved the issue.

[image: Model]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming the iterator output Name is being used in a select by attribute tool? If so feed the output of that into a Get Count tool and make that a precondition to your table to Excel tool. So if the selection fails get Count returns zero which will be interpreted as FALSE and will stop that part of the model executing, then on to the next iterator value.

Comment: Thank you! I played around with Get Count and it worked. Learning something new all the time.